# Rails order active records with assign_attributes

Tags: ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a User model which has a Scoring model which has a `score` value.
In my rails view I want to make an order of my users by score.
=> `User.joins (: scoring) .order (: score)`
So far, so good.
it gets complicated when I would dynamically change the score of some User without modifying them in the database according to certain attributes such as geolocation.
I tried the `assign_attributes` function but it does not change because the `.order` function calls the score fields in the database.

Use case: I do a user search by geolocation and the users near the geolocation appear in my search with their scores. I would like to weight the scores of users nearby since they are not on the exact geolocation

My code:

```
  #Get scoring in other geolocation
  @fiches_proxi = Fiche.joins(:user).merge(User.joins(:scoring)).near([@geo.lat_long_DMS.to_f, @geo.lat_long_grd.to_f], proxi_calcule(@geo.population_2012.to_i),units: :km, :order => 'scorings.score DESC').order('scorings.score DESC').where.not(geo: @geo.id).limit(10)

  #Get scoring in real geolocation
  @fiche_order_algo_all = Fiche.joins(:user).merge(User.joins(:scoring)).where(geo_id: @geo)

  #Find all scores
  @fiches_all = Fiche.where(id:  @fiche_order_algo_all.pluck(:id) +  @fiches_proxi.pluck(:id))

  @pagy, @fiche_order_algo = pagy(@fiches_all.joins(:user).merge(User.joins(:scoring).order('scorings.score DESC')), items: 12)

  @fiche_order_algo.each do |f|
    if f.geo.id != @geo.id
      f.user.scoring.assign_attributes(score: (f.user.scoring.score - 10.0))
    else
       f.user.scoring.score
    end
  end
```

My score is updated but my order is the same !

Comment: can you post the code you've tried?

Comment: Sur ! I update my message

Answer (score 0):

When you call `.each` on your relation, it returns an array, so you can use `Array#sort_by`

```
@fiche_order_algo.each do |f|
  if f.geo.id != @geo.id
    f.user.scoring.assign_attributes(score: (f.user.scoring.score - 10.0))
  else
     f.user.scoring.score
  end
end

@fiche_order_algo.sort_by!{|f| f.scoring.score}
```

If you're working with large data sets, this might not be optimized, but won't be any less efficient than what you already have.

But you can also do it in one go with:

```
@fiche_order_algo.sort_by! do |f|
  if f.geo.id != @geo.id
    f.user.scoring.assign_attributes(score: (f.user.scoring.score - 10.0))
  end
  f.user.scoring.score
end
```

Comment: I just tried and it's the same in my view, the order updated doesn't change

Comment: I was missing the bang on `sort_by!` which modifies the array it's called on.  Try it with the bang.